# Why do dxdiag and msinfo32 report differing amounts of Video RAM?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, directx-11

When I check my system specs in `msinfo32`, I see that I've got 256 MB "Adapter RAM" under `System Summary -> Components -> Display`.  However, `dxdiag` reports 2025 MB "Approximate Total Memory" on the "Display" tab.

What would cause such a discrepancy?  Are they both right, but measuring different things?

Comment: Integrated or discrete graphics?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It's a laptop, but I'm pretty sure the video RAM is dedicated.

Comment: These are the sort of details that are critical! ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dxdiag is reporting memory that is available to the system to be used to cache textures and data before it gets sent to the graphics card as well as physical memory on the graphics card.

MsInfo is only showing the memory physically available on the graphics card.